# Can questions which are closed and then deleted by the OP be undeleted?

Tags: support

Recently, I posted a question which I personally felt is suitable to ask and could be useful to the certain part of SO users. After seeing the first close vote, I created a flag for moderator attention and requested for deletion, and subsequently it was deleted by a moderator. However, I have a strong feeling that it should at least remain on SO (closed or reopened). Can I get this question in question undeleted?

Can questions which are closed and then deleted by the OP be undeleted?

Comment: Why did you ask for it do be deleted if you thought it had enough merit to exist?

Comment: @Oded I think, it was a momentarily deviation from a thought after reading a comment & seeing close vote.

Comment: Shame. If a moderator deleted it, I don't believe the community can vote to undelete. At least now you know not to be so hasty.

Comment: Given a moderator deleted it, I don't think you can undelete yourself. But if you still know the question id, then please try for yourself: [How do I undelete my question?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/101361/how-do-i-undelete-my-question/132859#132859) and let us know.

Comment: And please adjust your title to match the question. I get the feeling it was not closed (only one close vote) and you're writing a moderator deleted it?

Comment: @Arjan That was the status when I created the flag.

Comment: @Arjan Could not undelete after following the details in your link. Maybe I am not executing the process correctly. The id of question in question is 11280294.

Comment: [This is the question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11280294/pure-haskell-applications-free-and-available-for-download-or-websites) (for those that can see). That question would not be acceptable on [so] and if a moderator hadn't deleted it, the community would have.

Comment: You just need to learn how to use Google properly.  Stack Overflow is not a substitute for search engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was deleted by a moderator, only a moderator can undelete it. As it was not closed, the undeleted question would still be open, and it could be users will vote to close it.

Bear in mind that closing a question is the first step for deleting it. That is what happens to any closed question, except in the case the question was closed because it was a duplicate, but not an exact duplicate. If I ask a question, and then I re-ask it using the exact same words, then the second question is closed, and deleted.

Consider also that you should not keep asking for you question to be deleted, undeleted, and then deleted again. When you flag a question to delete it, be sure it's exactly what you want to do.